# Hibernate: OneToMany mapping failing

Tags: hibernate, duplicates, one-to-many

I'm new to Hibernate and attempting something which should be easy, but I can't get it to work.

There are two tables, a Person and an Address. A Person can have one or more Addresses, IE: A OneToMany mapping. I get an exception when I attempt to add the same address to two different people. It is almost as though Unique is enforced on the foriegn_key inside the 'join' table.

My source code:

**Person**

```
package testing.com.hibernate.entities;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person {
private long personID; 
private String personName;
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(0);

public Person() {}

public Person(String personName, Set<Address> addresses) {
    setPersonName(personName);
    setAddresses(addresses);
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
@Column(name="Person_ID")
public long getPersonID() {
    return personID;
}
@Column(name="Person_Name")
public String getPersonName() {
    return personName;
}
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "PersonAddresses", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="PersonID", unique=false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="AddressID", unique=false)})
public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}

public void setPersonID(long personID) {
    this.personID = personID;
}
public void setPersonName(String personName) {
    this.personName = personName;
}
public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}
}
```

**Address**

```
package testing.com.hibernate.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address {
private long addressID;
private String address; 

public Address() {}

public Address(String address) {
    setAddress(address);
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
@Column(name="Address_ID")
public long getAddressID() {
    return addressID;
}
@Column(name="Address")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddressID(long addressID) {
    this.addressID = addressID;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

**Main**

```
package testing.com.hibernate.tests;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import testing.com.hibernate.entities.Address;
import testing.com.hibernate.entities.EntityCategory;
import testing.com.hibernate.entities.EntityNetflixFilm;
import testing.com.hibernate.entities.Person;
import testing.com.hibernate.sessionmanager.HibernateUtil;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    // Create multiple addresses
    Address addr1 = new Address("Address one");
    Address addr2 = new Address("Address two");
    Address addr3 = new Address("Address three");
    Address addr4 = new Address("Address four");

    // Add all addresses to the database
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(addr1);
    session.save(addr2);
    session.save(addr3);
    session.save(addr4);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    /*
     * At this point in the code there will be four addresses 
     * in the table 'Address'. 
     * 
     * 1 - Address one
     * 2 - Address two
     * 3 - Address three
     * 4 - Address four
     * 
     * Now we want to create some people and add addresses to them
     */

    // Pull out a list of addresses from the database
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    addresses = session.createQuery("from Address").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    /*
     * We now have a List of Address objects.
     * 
     * This is replicating a Database with existing
     * Addresses and querying them from the table
     * to attach to a new Person being added. 
     */

    // Create person with Address 1 and 2
    Set<Address> addressSet1 = new HashSet<Address>();
    addressSet1.add(addresses.get(0));
    addressSet1.add(addresses.get(1));
    Person george = new Person("George", addressSet1);

    // Create person with Address 3 and 4
    Set<Address> addressSet2 = new HashSet<Address>();
    addressSet2.add(addresses.get(2));
    addressSet2.add(addresses.get(3));
    Person robert = new Person("Robert", addressSet2);

    // Create person with Address 1 and 2. The same as George
    Person harry = new Person("Harry", addressSet1);

    // Attempt to add them to the Person table
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(george);
    session.save(robert);
    session.save(harry);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
}
```

The code crashes at the point of saving Person object 'Harry'. This is because inside the PersonAddress table the Address with reference '1' is already present and assigned to 'George'. How can I make it so 'Harry' and 'George' can be mapped to Address '1'?

**Logs**

Hibernate: insert into Person (Person_Name, Person_ID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,284 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - George
22:39:42,284 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
Hibernate: insert into Person (Person_Name, Person_ID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,285 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - Robert
22:39:42,286 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 2
Hibernate: insert into Person (Person_Name, Person_ID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,287 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - Harry
22:39:42,287 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 3

Hibernate: insert into PersonAddresses (PersonID, AddressID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,289 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 1
22:39:42,292 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1

Hibernate: insert into PersonAddresses (PersonID, AddressID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,294 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 1
22:39:42,295 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 2

Hibernate: insert into PersonAddresses (PersonID, AddressID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,296 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 2
22:39:42,296 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 3

Hibernate: insert into PersonAddresses (PersonID, AddressID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,297 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 2
22:39:42,298 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 4

Hibernate: insert into PersonAddresses (PersonID, AddressID) values (?, ?)
22:39:42,298 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 3
22:39:42,300 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1

22:39:42,320  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
22:39:42,320 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'AddressID'

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'AddressID'

Answer (score 4):

Ok. So I figured out the problem myself.

It turns out Hibernate treats the 'Many' part of One-To-Many as unique entities in the join table. An example of this would be a car/service-history situation, you have one car which logs its unique service-history. If you try to add the service-history again to a different car it will fail as this service history is unique to a car already.

If you want to share information, in this case an Address which can be shared between multiple People you need a Many-to-Many relationship. To fix this update your source code so the Person has a @ManyToMany and supply the @JoinTable annotation.